# Excel Search from one sheet to another

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2007

I need some assistance with a search - I need to input a postal code in Cell A  and if it matches a postal code I have in another tab it will return the Suburb! So - Sheet 1 input Cell A1 will be postal code it will need to search Sheet 2 Column A for the postal code and once found Return back Suburb name in Sheet 2 Column B to sheet 1 Column B

Answer (score 0):

Use `VLOOKUP`.  Sheet 1 cell B1 would be:

```
    =VLOOKUP(A1,SHEET2!A1:Bnn,2,false)
```

Replace SHEET2 with the name of sheet 2.  I've shown the data range on sheet 2 as A1:Bnn; use whatever the last row number is for nn.  This looks up the value of sheet 1 cell A1 in the first column of the data range and returns the associated value from the second column of the range.  The false tells it to do an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])
```

Something like this works well

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet3!$A$1:$B$6,2, false)
```

This means

```
=VLookup(What value to look up, in this case A1, From where? Select entire table on Sheet2, Which column number has the value you want to return, false means an exact match)
```

So Sheet 1 is

[image]

And My other sheet shows

[image]

Please note, in my code, I am using Sheet3, you'll probably need to change that to Sheet2

This course may be helpful http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-RZ101862716.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx